# YouTube Data API is counting too many requests

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For the last few weeks, the YouTube Data API (v3) is showing a significant increase in requests. In fact, we hit the 50k quota limit every day, which means that requests in the afternoon/evening tend to fail with a quota exceeded error:

[image: quota chart]

However, this usage count is not correct. We use a single API key for making requests to the YouTube API, and the Google Cloud API counter only shows ~2k uses per day for that API key.

All requests to our server endpoint that calls the YouTube API also pass through Cloudflare, which similarly shows <2k requests per day.

We just make a single request to `www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&...` – is it possible that these requests count as multiple queries? Or is there any other reason that could explain the incorrect query counts? Thanks!

Comment: Seeing that your use `maxResults=1`, isn't that your call to `Search.list` polls for the newest video of a given (fixed) channel? If that's true, I'll indicate you a method to reduce the quota cost to one unit per endpoint call.

Comment: @Philipp Legner sorry to go off topic, but how did you get the 50K quota? I'm stuck at 10K and they never approve me for an increase. :/

Comment: Unfortunately, our request is a generic, free-form search query, and not just from a single channel. I couldn't find a different endpoint with a lower quota cost even if we just want a single result, but please let me know if I missed something. @010011100101, I'm not sure how the quota limit is chosen, but 50k seems to have been the default for us.

Comment: @Philipp Legner: If your query is of free-form kind, then there's not much else you could do. Irrespective of the concrete parameters one uses invoking `Search.list`, the quota cost of the call is always 100 units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [recurrent issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327133/8327971) with the YouTube Data API quota system, that is caused by confusing terms used within Google's cloud console.

You have to acknowledge that YouTube's Data API quota system is not accounting for the number of queries one is making. Instead, the API attaches to each kind of its endpoint a [*quota cost*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), and, thus, is accounting for the *sum of quota cost of all endpoint calls* one is making.

Moreover, inspecting the quota costs page I mentioned above (or the [official doc page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) of the endpoint for that matter), you'll see that the `Search.list` API endpoint is quite expensive: *100 units* of quota cost.

Consequently, to reach a quota cost of 50000 units, your app has to issue *only* 500 calls to `Search.list` (this amounts on average to approximately one call at every three minutes per day).

Comment: Please feel free to ask more info, if deeming that'll help you better.